# Improving efficiency with lazy/eager loading using a virtual (foreign key) reference

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am relatively new to Lambda/Linq, however I want to retrieve all events from a specific calendar where the events are still in the future...

If I use:

```
EventCalendar eventCalendar;
eventCalendar = db.Events_Calendars.Find(id);
```

I can get all events and filter by the current date in the view, but I don't think that is the best method.

The Model is as follows:

```
[Table("Events_Calendars")]
public class EventCalendar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Calendar { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Event Model is:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public int? Capacity { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The View is:

```
@model WebApps.Areas.Events.Models.EventCalendar
@* does some stuff with the EventCalendar *@

@Html.Partial("_Events", Model.Events.ToList())
```

_Events partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApps.Areas.Events.Models.Event>
.        
. 
. 
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.End > DateTime.Today)
        {
            @* Do that thing *@
        }    
    }
```

The above example works, but is putting logic flow in the view. I want to remove the filter logic from the view and make the query do all the work.

The following gives me the calendar only if it has at least one future event which is due to the same where clause conditions. I left it in as a reference of what I need to filter, yet it still returns all events both past and future:

```
eventCalendar = db.Events_Calendars
        .Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.End >= DateTime.Today) && x.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way that I can filter the events when I ask for the calendar and still use only one statement?

Note: Eager loading is defaulted to on with this system.

Edit clarification =  return "no more than 1 calendar with all associated future events";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Events.Any` will filter the `Events_Calendars` that have at least one event where `End >= DateTime.Today`. It will not filter the Events_Calendar.Events themselves.

The following will return the `Events.End >= DateTime.Today` for the matching Events_Calendar only.

```
var events = db.Events_Calendars
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Events)
    .Where(x => x.End >= DateTime.Today);
```

If you add a Events_Calendar property to the Events, you'll still be able to display the calendar.

Alternatively, you can remap the Events_Calendar, for example by using a factory method:

```
var newCal = Events_Calendars.WithFutureEvents(db.Events_Calendars.Find(id))

class Events_Calendar
{
    public static Events_Calendar WithFutureEvents(Events_Calendar cal)
    {
        return new Events_Calendar()
        {
            Id = cal.Id,
            Calendar = cal.Calendar,
            Events = cal.Events.Where(x => x.End >= DateTime.Today).ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

Note that the code example means the new Events_Calendar has reference copies for the Events.

Another possibility is a covenience method on Events_Calendar

```
class Events_Calendar
{
    public IEnumerable<Event> FutureEvents => Events.Where(e => e.End >= DateTime.Today);
}
```

Comment: I should mention that I edited the query statement about the same time you were writing your answer.to include a FirstOrDefault which is now giving me an issue with the SelectMany in your example. I like your idea of remapping, while I can't use it on this case, I will keep it in mind for future reference.

Comment: To clarify, I need no more than 1 calendar with all associated future events.

Comment: The remapping gives you exactly what you describe. `Find` returns the first calendar, the factory filters out all the events you do not want. I've added a third option: an extra property that gives you only those Events you are interested in.

Comment: Remapping worked as you said it would. Thanks! I will have to read up on factory filters and remapping. If you know of good explanations for beginners, feel free to post them.